# In MS SQL Server 2012: I have database name is J.3.0.0_DEV I'm unable to connect it in Oracle SQL Developer IDE?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, sql-server-2012, naming-conventions

In MS SQL Server 2012: I have database name is J.3.0.0_DEV  I'm unable to connect it in Oracle SQL Developer IDE due to name J.3.0.0_DEV.? All other database is working fine that has string name like JDev, JQA etc.

Note: I have configured third party driver for SQL Server 2012(jtds-1.3.1.jar & also I've try with sqljdbc4.jar or sqljdbc4-2.0.jar).So, Driver is working fine. I'm only unable to connect only name starting like J.3.0.0 etc.

Please give me solution.

Comment: please post the exception that causes de error.

Comment: Why do you name your database name with so many dots. Keep it simple to avoid problems.

Comment: During opening/ explore of object(J.3.0.0). Vendor code 102 Error occurred. Showing  incorrect syntax near '.3'

Comment: Other is working good with same connection that has string type database name. ( I have problem with database name not connection name.)

Comment: @Raptor this is my client database name. I can't change it. This name was using since 8-10 yrs.